# "The SMTP host was not specified." - but it is specified?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm slightly baffled here - I'm receiving the following error:

> The SMTP host was not specified.

Even though my code appears to be correct (from what I can see).

I am able to do it manually by including all the details inside of the controller, e.g.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtpClient.Port = 587;
... etc
```

But I shouldn't have to do this, as I want to use the details inside `mailSettings` (Making it re-usable for various different controllers).

`mailSettings` in my `Web.Config` file:

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="example@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network" >
       <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="true" 
                port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="example@gmail.com"
                password="example"/>
     </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

My Controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SubmitFeature(FormData formData)
 {
     SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
     mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@gmail.com"));
     mail.Body = "Test";

     smtpClient.Send(mail);

     return View("Example");
 }
```

Is there anything I'm missing which may be causing this? I haven't messed around with any other settings in Web.Config, they are as is when setting up a new MVC5 project.

Comment: Any chance you added this to "Release.Web.Config" instead of the actual Web.Config?

Comment: @flaviotsf Nope, it's inside Web.Config. Am I supposed to reference using the Web Config inside the controller elsewhere or?

Comment: I believe you should change `defaultCredentials` to `false` to authenticate with provided credentials.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I receive the exact same error after this change sadly

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a clean MVC project, I am unable to replicate your issue.  Following the [ScottGu blog post here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx), I was able to get a gmail sent email without issue (VS 2013, .NET 4.5.1, MVC 5).  Note the the `<system.net>` element is a top level element and not nested inside of `AppSettings` or `<system.web>`.

**Important**

There are a few web.config files in your solution, ensure that the `mailSettings` is inserted into the root level web.config (and not the one located in the Views folder)

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myEmail@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
                 port="587" 
                 enableSsl="true" 
                 userName="myEmail@gmail.com" 
                 password="SuperSecretPwd" 
                 defaultCredentials="false" /> <!--This must be false on Gmail-->
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**Controller**

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
var msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("MyOtherAddress@yahoo.com");
msg.Subject = "Test";
msg.Body = "This is just a test email";
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

It is unclear if some of the extra attributes you have included are causing issues (thought they shouldn't) such as delivery method.  Also, is there a setting for allowing SMTP access or is that just for IMAP/POP delivery?

If you can test and are successful in a clean project, then this would point to either a web.config transformation problem or some other setting(s) in your project overriding the web.config settings that you have in place.

Comment: Hello, I am actually able to send emails, however I have to specify the attributes (such as port, enableSsl) inside the controller. The `Web.Config` file doesn't seem to have any effect at all. When I change `new SmtpClient();` to `new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");`, I actually receive a different error - "A from address must be specified", which makes me think the `Web.Config` file isn't even being recognised?

Comment: @user2945993 - thats what I am saying though.  I can set this up in the web.config and it works without issue.  Can you try the code I posted above in a new/clean project?  Do you still have the issues?

Comment: @user2945993  Are you 100% that these values are not being overwritten by a web.config transformation?  Are you debugging  locally or publishing to a server?

Comment: I'm unsure if they're being overridden - just testing a new project now and will let you know.

Comment: @user2945993 - good deal.  Literally copy the code I have above and replace the necessary values.  Also, the `<system.net>` is a top level web.configuration element.  Ensure you don't have it buried under some other element (like inside system.web or appSettings)

Comment: It works 100% fine in a new project. You're right, I'm going to have to look at what could be overriding this.

Comment: @user2945993  Good deal.  Double check your configuration settings, make sure you don't have a funny typo, elements in wrong position inside the configuration file and that the compiler isn't transforming and erasing your settings.  Beyond that, I am not sure I can help much more at this point :/

Comment: Thanks. Would seeing my config file help? I could chuck it in a pastebin quick.

Comment: @user2945993 - sure, just be sure to scrub PWDs out of there first :)

Comment: @user2945993  let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45595/discussion-between-tommy-and-user2945993)

Answer (score 5):

The solution was mentioned in the [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45595/discussion-between-tommy-and-user2945993), but never edited into the answer above.

Make sure that you make these settings in the `web.config` of the **Root Level** and not in the Views folder.

> @Tommy: [...this looks like the web.config from your Views folder and not the web.config at the root of the application](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14161258#14161258)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is right so,Turn on "Less secure app access" in your Gamil email account[image]