# contact page form throws error MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been banging my head trying to figure out what's wrong here. I'm new to c# and fairly new to MVC in general. I need a small, simple email contact form for my website. I'm not exactly sure what the rhyme or reason is, but the controller will register all the fields for the form, but skips `smtp.Send(msg);` and jumps right to the catch method. I tried adding a `[GET]` method after the `[POST]` which I've read helps, but still no luck. I have a feeling it is a problem with the smtp ports or host, but I can't find any documentation.

Also, I tried adding some snippets for button functionality too, but no luck either. Any help would be great.

**Model**

```
public class ContactModels
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Your name is required")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your email is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your phone number is required")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must type a message")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p><strong>Phone: </strong>586.xxx.xxxx</p>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong><a href="mailto:Tom@blank.com">example@example.com</a></p>
    <p><strong>Address: </strong>Address Here</p>

    <h3>Connect with us through Email </h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FullName, "Name: ")
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.FullName)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Email, "Email: ")
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Phone, "Phone: ")
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Phone)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Comment, "Message: ")
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Comment)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Comment)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(Models.ContactModels c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                msg.To.Add("myEmailHere@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                smtp.Port = 993;

                sb.Append("Name: " + c.FullName);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                sb.Append("Email: " + c.Email);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                sb.Append("Phone: " + c.Phone);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                sb.Append("Comment: " + c.Comment);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                msg.Body = sb.ToString();
                smtp.Send(msg);
                msg.Dispose();

                return View("Success");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Change `catch(Exception)` to `catch(Exception ex)` and put a breakpoint there and inspect the ex variable to get more info about the error.

Comment: @Shyju the ex variable reads a null value

Comment: The `ex` variable in `catch(Exception ex)` should show you the Exception type, the message, and most importantly the stack trace which should give you exactly which method is failing. Most likely you are doing string concatination above with one of those properties having a `null` value. Also you should dispose all your disposables using either a using block or a finally block like `SmtpClient`.

Comment: 'A from address must be specified' when I hover over ex when it hits the breakpoint.

Comment: There you go. I hope that error message is obvious.

Comment: Have you tried this with port 587 ?

Comment: @Shyju obvious enough to understand what it means. apparently not obvious enough to know how to fix it.

Comment: @kkakkurt I just tried changing the port to 587 but yet still, the same errors are thrown. All the info is correct, but I'm not sure how to fix the 'A from address must be specified' problem.

Comment: Can you add "smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;" line in your controller and try again?

Comment: @kkakkurt I tried adding it, along with changing the smtp port back to 993 and same error is being thrown.

Comment: You can try defining smpt settings in your "Web.config".
There is a pure solution about this way:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21221825/3401842

Comment: @kkakkurt That was something I never knew about. I tried messing around with it a few different ways. still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
```

Comment: I just tried that a few minutes ago from @shyju 's comment. Now it hits the smtp.Send(msg) line and reads all the correct info, but still jumps to the Error view. Also, variable 'ex' is never used. I'm not sure why it skips the Success view still.